# Yii2 mysql deal with bigger data

Tags: mysql, yii2

is there any way in which we can deal with a large number of data.
Like here is my code which failed with "`Allowed memory size of 524288000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)`"

```
$amount_needed = 0;
$openWo = Production::find()->where(['fulfilled'=>0])->all(); // it returns 10k records
foreach ($openWo as $value) {
  $amount_needed += $value->amount_needed;
  $item = Item::findOne($value->item_id); // so this will fire a query 10k times
  $materials = Materials::find()->where(['item_id'=>$value->item_id])->all(); // so this will fire a query 10k times
  foreach ($materials as $val) {
       //much more here....
  }
  //much more here....
}
```

so here the first foreach will 10k times. and again there are other queries and again foreach loop...

**So is there any way I can work with large data in mysql+yii2 or do I need to switch from MySQL to other database?**

Comment: You could try to replace `all()` with `each()`.

Comment: Queries should not be in loop. Find another way to query the db first. Extract all `item_id` from `$openWo` and run queries before loop and if you don't need active record use `asArray()->all()`.